# How to execute code after all rows of array has been read using Readline module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to input an array of strings to my program using readline module.
an example:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const r = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout
});

var arr = [];

r.on('line', (line) => {
   arr.push(line)
   //code that run for every line
})
```

I want to execute code after all the lines in the array that i input are finished, is there an efficient way to do that? Or is there a way to check if the last line has been read?

sample array to be input:

```
arr = [
    'Maria Martinez',
    'James Johnson',
    'Maria Garcia',
    'David Smith'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an event handler for the [`close` event](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-close) that will indicate when all the lines have been processed.

```
r.on('close', () => {
    // done processing all lines now
    console.log(arr);
});
```

And, probably should also be listening for the `error` event too.

Comment: Then it runs only after i exit the program, or at least i get the output of my program after i exit.

Comment: @Milandro - Where is stdin coming from in your program?  From console?  Or piped from a file?  If from a console, you have to terminate the input somehow.

Comment: nevermind, it works, Thanks alot!